# Private profile for users | rails 4 | devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to implement a private profile page for each user. It's an learning app so people have access to the courses they paid for on their profile page. So other users can't access profile pages by entering URLs... The http response should be 404.

So far the idea was to create a profiles_controller

```
def show
    @user = User.find(current_user)
End
```

So that each user can only access their own page.

Is there a best way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Think of an ideal solution.** The one where **the problem doesn't even exist**. Given the problem

> *"the user should not see other users' profiles"*

we can build upon a principle

> *"there is only one profile for any user"*

And we should reflect that mapping in our routes:

```
resource :profile # < not `resources`!
```

...and the profile will be available on `/profile`. No ids in your routes whatsoever, nothing to alter, therefore nothing to check. And it makes sense, why check anything, if we'll be working with the same resource anyway?

```
# ProfilesController
def show
  @user = current_user
end
```

Comment: That was actually what I had

Comment: @D-side Suppose a user's profile id is 3, and then he types in the brower `/profiles/4`, how would you stop him seeing anyone else's profile?

Comment: Thing is there is no model profile, it's just the controller so whenever I try to access another id it redirects to my own profile.

Comment: But yeah that was my problem

Comment: @ArslanAli `/profiles/4` does not match my route rules at all.

Comment: @AdrienNhm it's a controller that is responsible for interaction of a logged in user with his own profile. Nothing else. For interacting with other users' profiles you'd have to create another one.

Comment: Cheers guys :) really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can `before_action` for `show` method in `ProfilesController`. Basically, you need to check that the profile a user can view - belongs only to that user.

I assume the URL is `/users/:user_id/profiles/:id`

```
before_filter :check_profile, only: :show

def check_profile
  user = User.find_by_id params[:user_id]
  unless params[:id] == user.profile.id
    redirect_to users_profiles_path(user, user.profile)
  end
end
```

This way, user will be redirected to his own profile path, whenever he'd try to access someone else's profile.